# unexpected ruby global array variable behaviour

Tags: ruby, fork

I have this code:

```
require 'pp'

$pool = []

def work arg
    $pool.push($$)
    sleep (1 + rand(5))
    $pool.delete($$)
    exit
end

ary = []
100.times { |x| ary.push(x) }

while ary.any? do 
    while $pool.size < 10 && ary.any?
        arg = ary.pop
        Process.detach( fork { work(arg) } )
        pp $pool.size
        sleep 0.01
    end
end
```

for me it's unexpected when I am filling `$pool` in `work()` `pp $pool.size` in second `while` loop always `0`

where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a new process with fork the new process gets a copy of the (empty) $pool. The $pool in the parent process which executes the loop is never populated with anything (the call to work function is executed in the child process), so it's size is always 0.

Comment: Okay, thank you.
But what should I change in my code to get needed behaviour?

Comment: You need to work with the $pool in the parent process. Take the return value of fork first, this is the child process id and put it into the $pool. Actually, the fork call returns twice, once in the parent, returning the process ID of the child, and once in the child, returning nil. Read this: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Process.html#M001281

Comment: Sorry, don't understand.
Need what?

Comment: Sorry, I pressed enter by an accident, I just edited the previous comment, read it now.

Comment: `fork` returns a value.  Both the parent AND the forked child continue execution.  The only thing that differs between them is what the return value of `fork` was.  You use this to determine if you are the child or the parent.  If you're the child, you need to break out of the loop.  If you're the parent, you (probably) need to continue looping.  If the return value of `fork` is `nil`, you are the child, and must exit the loop.

Comment: Sorry, Ruby handles things a little differently to other languages.  Ignore my last comment.  However, because you are modify `$pool` from inside of your children, which are operating in a separate memory space (completely separate process) the parent process will never see any changes, since that value is not changed in the parent.

Comment: `pid = fork { work(arg) }; $pool << pid; Process.detach(pid);`